# Renderpartial in a foreach loop only sends the first element in list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm trying to send a User in a list of users to a partial view but the partial view only takes the first user in the list. The code correctly displays the username and the actionlink to profile but for some reason only the first user in the list is sent to the partial view in every iteration.

What I want to do is to dynamically show the "confirmDelete" partial view when the delete button is clicked and delete the correct user.

Help is appreciated!

**Edit:**
I think I see the problem now, I name the url pointing to the Delete-Action "RedirectTo" in every partial view, and also all the divisions have the same id.. Still don't know how to fix it though.

MainView:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.UsersList as List<CommonLibrary.User>)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Profile", "ProfilePage", new { id = item.UserId }) |
            @{
                var user = Homepage.Service.SessionHelper.GetSessionUser(Context);
                if (user != null && user.GetType().ToString() == "CommonLibrary.Operator" && item.UserId != user.UserId)
                {
                    <button id="@item.UserId" class="btn-danger" onclick="confirmDelete()">Delete</button>
                    <div style="width:40%; float:right;">

                        @{

                            await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ConfirmDelete", item);
                        }
                    </div>

                }
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Partial View:

```
@model CommonLibrary.User

@Html.Hidden("RedirectTo", Url.Action("Delete", "Users", new { id = Model.UserId }))
<div style="display:none" id="confDelete">
    <div>
        <b>Are you sure you want to delete user: @Model.UserName?</b>
    </div>
    <button id="Yes" class="btn-danger" onclick="deleteConfirmed()">Yes</button>
    <button id="No" class="btn-secondary" onclick="hideDelete()">No</button>
</div>

<script>
    function confirmDelete() {
        $("#confDelete").show();
        $("#del_btn").hide();
    }
    function hideDelete() {
        $("#confDelete").hide();
        $("#del_btn").show();
    }
    function deleteConfirmed() {
        var url = $("#RedirectTo").val();
        location.href = url;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using UserId as id for the different elements.

Main View:

```
  <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.UsersList as List<CommonLibrary.User>)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Profile", "ProfilePage", new { id = item.UserId }) |
                    @{
                        var user = Homepage.Service.SessionHelper.GetSessionUser(Context);
                        if (user != null && user.GetType().ToString() == "CommonLibrary.Operator" && item.UserId != user.UserId)
                        {
                            <button id="@item.UserId" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="confirmDelete(this.id)">Delete</button>
                            <div style="width:40%; float:right;">
                                @{
                                    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ConfirmDelete", item);
                                }
                            </div>

                        }
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    function confirmDelete(id) {
        var element = document.getElementById("div" + id);
        element.style.display = "block";
    }
    function hideDelete(id) {
        var element = document.getElementById("div" + id);
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
    function deleteConfirmed(id) {
        var url = "/Users/Delete/" + id;
        window.location.href = url;
    }
</script>
```

Partial View:

```
@model CommonLibrary.User

@{
    var divId = "div" + Model.UserId.ToString();
}
<div style="display:none" id="@divId">
    <div>
        <b>Are you sure you want to delete user: @Model.UserName?</b>
    </div>
    <button id="@Model.UserId.ToString()" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteConfirmed(this.id)">Yes</button>
    <button id="@Model.UserId.ToString()" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="hideDelete(this.id)">No</button>
</div>
```